# JPQL query --- how to use 'is null'

Tags: jpql

i use the following query in JPQL to query the people whose address column is empty.

> List rl =
>                   em.createQuery( "select o from Person as o where
>   o.address IS NULL" ).setFirstResult(
>   0).setMaxResults( 50).getResultList();
>   ...

this line of code always return an empty list, obviously the table does has entries that match the condition.

> class Person {
>       Address address;
>       String name;
>       ... } 
>   class Address {
>       String name;
>       ... }

anyone knows what's wrong with this jpql statement?
thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way, i find that when i use "is not null", it will generate the right result list. but if use "is null", every time it will generate nothing at all

Comment: are you using @OneToMany & what are referential integrity constraints.

Comment: yes, does that affact JPA query?  as below:
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE } )
@Column( name = "AddressID" )
private Address address;

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As mentioned, address column is empty, then try using **IS EMPTY** expression instead of **IS NULL**.

```
em.createQuery( "SELECT o FROM Person o where (o.address.id IS NULL OR o.address.id = 0").setMaxResults(50).getResultList();
```

Check constraint according to id's datatype.

Also there is no need to mention **setFirstResult(0)** as it is not going to skip any results & without it, by default all matching results will be fetched.

Comment: thanks for your reply. however i don't think "is Empty" will do good job. as the spec said, is empty is used to check if a collection is empty or not. if used it will pop exception:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invocation of method "size" on "java.lang.Object" is not supported
 at org.datanucleus.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:264)
 at org.datanucleus.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:177)

Comment: fixed, turned out to be datanucleus's bug. thansk anyway